# Autodesk Integration - Search in folders without 3-legged token

Tags: rest, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'am trying to implement an integration with Autodesk Construction Cloud, and I want to allow users to perform search within Project Files folder. What I'am working on rn is a Files Viewer.

It seems like search requests can be only used with 3-legged auth token([documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/)), it seems super strange, because we can easily navigate on all folders and find required files manually without required user context, so I cannot understand why 3-legged token required here, but it is not the question.

**I want to implement search without 3-legged token, so question here is what will be the best approach to implement files search within folders and subfolders using Forge API without required user context?** I guess that somebody who knows Forge API can suggest me some good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, [search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/) requires 3LO and the great advantage here is that you can use it recursively.

To avoid the need of 3LO you can use [Get folder contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) recursively, as we did [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/reading-bim360acc-project-recursively).

Note that you can also combine [filters](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/#multiple-filters) with this request,
and take advantage of [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) for searching.

There's also a sample using Elasticsearch [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-bim-360-search-elasticsearch) (in this case to search based on models metadata).